# OP Amp 0-5 VDC Output

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, potentiometer

I have the circuit pictured below.  I need to change the potentiometer from a 20K to a 5K and still get the 0-5 VDC output.  VCC = 5V

- Is this possible?
- What needs to change to make this possible?
- What is this circuit called, a buffer?

Also, can a LM258 Op Amp do the same as the ICL7612?  (I have a lot of the LM258's on hand, but would have to order the 7612.)  I breadboarded a similar circuit using the LM258, but the output saturates at about 2.5V and will not go higher.

[image: OP Amp Analog Circuit]

Comment: Ouch.  Head hurts.  Check your supply 'headroom'. [https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-62.html](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-62.html)

Comment: Check the duplicate https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/273081/potentiometer-value-if-i-used-it-as-voltage-divider for your first question.

Answer (score 1):

> What is this circuit called? A buffer?

Unity gain voltage buffer.

> Is this possible? What needs to change to make this possible?

Look for an opamp that is rail to rail (input and output) compatible, this will ensure that the output can swing rail to rail. Op amps that don't operate rail to rail will have trouble reaching Vcc.

Answer (score 0):

It's an op-amp non-inverting buffer and if Vcc is 5 volts you will never get exactly 5 volts on the output no matter what op-amp you choose. If the most negative supply on the op-amp is 0 volts you will never get the op-amp output to reach 0 volts either.

Most rail-to-rail op-amps can get to within a few tens of mV of either rail when very lightly loaded - you hit the limit of what the output transistors can do.

Comment: Anyone care to share the reason for my answer being downvoted?

Comment: Hi Andy.  Not the down-voter, but "no matter what op-amp you choose" breaks the 'it depends' rule.  There are amps with built in supply generators to produce the necessary supply overhead for true rail-to-rail-ness.  Obviously not what the OP is considering, but _possible_. However, I'm certain that you're referring to similar opamp solutions to what the OP mentions.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen maybe you can provide a link to one?

Comment: Quick search: [http://www.ti.com/product/OPA388](http://www.ti.com/product/OPA388).  True R2R Input. However, still 5mV from the output rails (Vs: 2.5 to 5.5 V).  Perhaps an actual production chip with true R2R I/O is mythical.  I didn't look beyond the first google page.

Comment: I think so hehe.

Answer (score 0):

While your second question regarding the Opamp is already covered by other answers, I would like to give you a simple answer to your first question:

> I have the circuit pictured below. I need to change the potentiometer from a 20K to a 5K and still get the 0-5VDC output. VCC = 5V
>
> Is this possible? What needs to change to make this possible?

**Yes, it is possible without any changes.**
Your potentiometer is nothing else than a voltage divider, the only thing that matters for output voltage is the ratio of the "upper" resistor to the "lower" resistor. Or in the case of a potentiometer the ratio between the resistance between Pin 1 to Pin 2 and the resistance between Pin 2 and Pin 3. This does not change with the overall resistance of the potentiometer, if you turn the potentiometer to the middle position, you will always have half the input voltage.

But I have to constrain this general answer a little bit: In an *unloaded* voltage divider the resistance would not matter, in practice you have some kind of load at your middle tap. If this load is to big compared to the resistance of the voltage divider you ouput voltage would go down. But in your case the output connects to the input of an OpAmp, which will draw almost no current at all, so you can choose from a pretty wide rage of potentiometers. So simply changing the potentiometer from 20k to 5k will change nothing (except that the bias current of your voltage divider will rise from 0.25 mA to 1 mA).

But keep in mind the other answers: With a 5V single supply you will get issues achieving 0...5V output voltage!